# Unity Google Play leaderboards UI crashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

i am trying to get the google leaderboards working for my android game. The login works well and tested with correct signing etc. The achievements work fine aswell but when it comes to displaying leaderboards it just crashes as soon as the user opens it. It crashes only when a new highscore is submitted. If I reset the leaderboard from the google console and restart the app, it opens fine but ofcourse with no records. I am using c# within unity. I have tried various methods to the following but to no avail.

```
    #region Leaderboards
public static void AddScoreToLeaderboard(string leaderboardId, long score)
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        Social.ReportScore(score, leaderboardId, (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Update Score Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Update Score Fail");
            }
        });
    }
}


public static void ShowLeaderboardsUI()
{
    Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
}
#endregion /Leaderboards
```

And then im calling the ShowLeaderboardsUI() method from the button. Any ideas of what I should try please? or maybe u have encountered this issue before? Thanks alot.

Edit:

> Logcat
>   I/Unity   (17385):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/18/18 21:18:45 +02:00 DEBUG:  Showing UI Internal callback: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
>   I/Unity   (17385):
>   I/Unity   (17385): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
>   I/Unity   (17385):
>   I/Unity   (17385):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/18/18 21:18:45 +02:00 DEBUG:   Invoking user callback on game thread
>   I/Unity   (17385):
>   I/Unity   (17385): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
>   I/Unity   (17385):
>   I/Unity   (17385):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/18/18 21:18:45 +02:00 DEBUG:
>    Received UI callback: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
>   I/Unity   (17385):
>   I/Unity   (17385): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
>   I/Unity   (17385):

Comment: Are there any error messages from Unity or Android?

Comment: edited the logcat